# Lovasz theta function - uses

Tags: co.combinatorics, big-list, linear-programming, spectral-graph-theory, coding-theory

Lovasz theta function bounds the Shannon capacity of graphs. What are some other uses of the function - especially in asymptotic coding theory and optimization problems?

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like "co.combinatorics". I added this tag now.

Answer (score 3):

Schrijver long ago established a connection to the Delsarte bound for a 
[Hamming association scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_scheme):
A. Schrijver, "A comparison of the Delsarte and Lovasz bounds," [*IEEE Transactions on Information Theory*, 25: 425-429 (1979)](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=1056072&abstractAccess=no&userType=inst).

Comment: @Joseph: Good reference. So is there a spectral characterization of minimum distance bounds in particular the GV bound?

Comment: Sorry, unknown, I do not know.

Answer (score 2):

One of the most important properties of the Lovász theta function is that for any $\epsilon >0$, it can be approximated to within an $\epsilon$ additive error in polynomial time (by the Ellipsoid Method).

Moreover, for every graph $G$, it is well-known that

$$\alpha(G) \leq \vartheta(G) \leq \overline{\chi}(G),$$

where $\alpha(G)$ is the size of a largest independent in $G$, $\vartheta(G)$ is the Lovasz theta number of $G$, and $\overline{\chi}(G)$ is the chromatic number of the complement of $G$.

For perfect graphs, we have $\alpha(G) = \vartheta(G) = \overline{\chi}(G)$.  In particular $\vartheta(G)$ is always an integer.  Therefore, rounding an approximation of the Lovász theta function yields a polynomial-time algorithm to compute the chromatic number of perfect graphs.  As far as I know, no other efficient algorithm is known.